# SQL Nested Query with Store Function

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to execute a nested query. In the first SELECT statement, I am fetching all the guestID that have type as guest and calculated distance less than the specified value.

I have created a getDistance(lat1, long1, lat2, long2) to calculate distance between two points. My problem here is that in my nested query that I am performing on the users table, I have both user_id and distance in the SELECT query. So the first quest on guest won't simply work because there is both user_id and distance in the nested query.

Where can I accurately put the getDistance function so that the whole query work. Or is there a way to select only user_id from the nested query for the primary query?

```
SELECT guestId 
FROM guest 
WHERE user_id IN (
    SELECT user_id, getDistance(lati, longi, ?, ?) as distance 
    FROM users 
    WHERE type = 'Guest' 
    HAVING (distance <= ?)
```

Comment: I removed the PHP code and tag as I can't see how this relates to PHP. Also, you are missing a closing bracket in your SQL

Comment: What else do you need to distance when you get guestId? This column is useless

Comment: @MeysamAsadi I am using the distance to filter out certain entries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this do what you want?

```
SELECT guestId 
FROM guest 
WHERE user_id IN (
    SELECT user_id
    FROM users 
    WHERE type = 'Guest'
    AND getDistance(lati, longi, ?, ?) <= ?)
```

Comment: Apparently, the function getDistance is not working somehow. Lemme do some check on that.

Answer (score 1):

I calculated the `distance` inside a subquery and redirected it to the external select, where you can use `having` and just return the `user_id`.

***Also, having needs a group by, and I probably set it to user_id.***

```
SELECT guestId 
FROM guest 
WHERE user_id IN (
        SELECT user_id  
        FROM
        (
           SELECT user_id,getDistance(lati, longi, ?, ?) as distance 
           FROM users 
           WHERE type = 'Guest'  
        ) T1
        GROUP BY user_id
        HAVING (distance <= ?))
```